# How to put character if there is one digit in cell in VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask, how to put character, in this case `0` to cell, if the cell already contains digit in it. 
To clarify what do I mean, if on the cell is number `5`, I would like to put before the number `5`, number `0` to have the result `05`.

As far as I know, cell format should be TEXT to avoid automatic Excel correction. But, this question is specific due to several different characters in the cells. In some point I got in the same column different characters in the cells (`1`, `2`, `3`, `AV`, `AR`, `IX` etc.).

For example: I would like to select column K, find the numeric characters with one digit (`1`, `2`, `3`, `-9`) and paste there `0` before it to have two space digit like `01`, `02`, `03`, …

Of course, with macro. I know how to put Text format to it, but do not know how to manage the whole macro function to select column K, format whole column as text, find one digit number in the column and paste `0` before it.

Does anybody know how to do that?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not apply a custom number format with "00"? That way the numbers will remain as numbers and you don't need to format the column as Text.

Comment: I suggest you do some research, try something, then come back with any specific problem you're having with your attempt.

Comment: If the cell content is `-9` then it should be `-09` or `09`?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Format the numbers
2. Convert numbers to text and format them

#### 1. Format the numbers

The advantage of this solution is that the numbers will still be numbers (not text) but formatted with leading zeros. Therefore you still can calculate with these numbers as before.

```
Public Sub ChangeNumberFormat()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourDesiredSheetName").Columns("K").NumberFormat = "00"
    'this will keep them numbers but only change the format of them
End Sub
```

Note that you don't need to do this necessarily with VBA you can just set a user defined cell format `00` for column K (open format cells with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>).

---

#### 2. Convert numbers to text and format them

If you really need to convert them to text this would be a possible solution. But I really don't recommend that because you cannot calculate with these "numbers" anymore because they are converted to text.

The trick would be to format the number with numberformat first and then convert it to text (see comments in the code).

```
Option Explicit 'force variable declaring

Public Sub FixLeadingZerosInText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourDesiredSheetName") '<-- change your sheet name here

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row  'find last used row in column K

    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In ws.Range("K1:K" & lRow)          'loop from row 1 to last used in column K
        If iCell.Value < 10 And iCell.Value > -10 Then 'check if it is a one digit number
            Dim tmpText As String
            tmpText = Format(iCell.Value, "00")        'format the one digit number
            iCell.NumberFormat = "@"                   'convert number to text
            iCell.Value = tmpText                      're-write formatted number
        End If
        iCell.NumberFormat = "@" 'make all other numbers in column K formatted as text too
    Next iCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peh,  But the cells are still remaining like "General" format in whole column.  I did manual format reclass to Text and after macro run, its automatically switched to General. Also if you have 0 in the cell, it supposed to be 00. I tryed to macro by different solutions how to include 0 before the digit 1,2,3..but its still replacing me whole column for 00 which is not possible. There are several different codes like 0, 2, which shoudl include also 0 like 00,02,...but also text characters AC, EF, etc. which should not be overwritten.

Comment: With the first code (1) all cells in column K become usere defined format `"00"`. With the second code (2) (if you did not change anything) all non-empty cells in column K will be format "Text". All `0` become `00`. So I don't see any issues. If you think something goes wrong then please give a detailed example what the (a) source data is, (b) what my code makes out of it and (c) what you expect it to be!